# Is AWS SNS a scaled out version of the observer pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, design-patterns, amazon-sns

The observer pattern talks about publishers and subscribers. Isn't this something real close to what AWS SNS does? A notification is broadcasted to all the subscribers which might be SQS queues, email addresses, etc.
What are the notable differences if there are any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always considered SNS to be a *distributed implementation* of the observer pattern. And heres is why; imagine that you have to distribute notifications to different actors of a workflow - lots of people interested in knowing that a certain state was achieved in your app.

If you try to implement the observer pattern within a single instance you will be limited to memory and CPU constraints, no matter how much you scale up you will hit a limit anytime. If you happen to have hundreds of thousands of notifications to be processed then you will end up delaying a lot, sometimes to the point that it is no longer valuable to know that the application was at that certain state. You will end up having to scale out your observer pattern implementation - but hey it seems that someone has already done that.

This is what the observer pattern looks like, [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

[image: Observer pattern according to Wikipedia]

We can now try to figure out if SNS will fit;

1. We need a central guy that will take care of notifying everyone in time.
2. We need to be able to notify different kinds of observers.
3. We need to be able to register and unregisters observers on the fly.
4. We need to be able to retrieve everyone subscribed to be notified.

If SNS does all these things than we have a [bird quacking like a duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) - I mean, it can be anything but I know it is also an implementation of the observer pattern.

Now lets see [what methods are available in SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html):

1. We can [create a topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#createTopic-property) - the central guy who owns a list of subscribed observsers.
2. We can [subscribe](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#subscribe-property) to this topic with different protocols. You should only know the [interface used to communicate with these various endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/json-formats.html#http-notification-json), which in the case of SNS in plain HTTP (among others).
3. Yes, we can manage who is listening to notifications with subscribe and its analogous [unsubscribe](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#unsubscribe-property).
4. We can [list everyone](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#listSubscriptions-property) willing to get a touch when an event happens on your app.
5. And of course, we can [publish](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#publish-property) to notify everyone!

I then ask you, why can't SNS be considered a scaled out version of the observer pattern? Its quacking like a duck!

Answer (score 3):

The observer pattern is generally [understood](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000SEIBB8) to include a subject that maintains a list of dependent observers.  If you consider the SNS topic itself to be the subject, then  yes it is a fit for the pattern.  However, in this understanding the SNS topic has no knowledge of it's own state and doesn't notify observers on it's own behalf -- it is a proxy for others.

SNS is perhaps better understood as a [multiplexer](http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~laks/ADCS-2013-Fall/CM-CEP-Survey.pdf) in the context of event based systems.

Comment: I agree with you on the part that SNS does not itself decide when to send the notification, but it does hold the data of whom all to notify when "someone" says that the state has changed. 
But isn't the observer pattern the same? The subject is just responsible for sending out notifications to observers and not how its state got altered, isn't it?